# error: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int when trying to merge two sorted arrays

Tags: java

Trying to merge two sorted arrays together but I'm receiving an error:

error: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int

I did some research but I couldn't really figure out why this is happening. I know my program is having an issue with the sorted  array but I'm not sure what the fix would be.

Here is my code:

```
public class MedianOfTwoSortedArrays 
{   
    //[1,2],{3,4}
    static int[] nums1 = new int[]{1, 3};
    static int[] nums2 = new int[]{2};


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println(findMedianSortedArrays(nums1, nums2));
    }

        public static int findMedianSortedArrays(int[] nums1, int[] nums2) 
        {
            int[] sorted = new int[nums1.length + nums2.length];
            int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

            while (i < nums1.length && j < nums2.length)
            {
                if (nums1[i] < nums2[j])
                {
                    sorted[k] = nums1[i];
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    sorted[k] = nums2[j];
                    j++;
                }
                k++;
            }

            while (i < nums1.length)
            {
                sorted[k] = nums1[i];
                i++;
                k++;
            }

            while (j < nums2.length)
            {
                sorted[k] = nums2[j];
                j++;
                k++;
            }

            return sorted;
        }

}
```

Comment: Which line is the error detected in?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first mistake you are doing is that you are returning int array and your method return type is int.

```
    public class MedianOfTwoSortedArrays 
    {   
        //[1,2],{3,4}
        static int[] nums1 = new int[]{1, 3};
        static int[] nums2 = new int[]{2};


        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            int a[] = findMedianSortedArrays(nums1, nums2);

            for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
                System.out.println(a[i]);
            }
          }

            public static int[] findMedianSortedArrays(int[] nums1, int[] nums2) 
            {
                int[] sorted = new int[nums1.length + nums2.length];
                int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

                while (i < nums1.length && j < nums2.length)
                {
                    if (nums1[i] < nums2[j])
                    {
                        sorted[k] = nums1[i];
                        i++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sorted[k] = nums2[j];
                        j++;
                    }
                    k++;
                }

                while (i < nums1.length)
                {
                    sorted[k] = nums1[i];
                    i++;
                    k++;
                }

                while (j < nums2.length)
                {
                    sorted[k] = nums2[j];
                    j++;
                    k++;
                }

                return sorted;
            }

    }
```

you have to store the result in array and loop over it.

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix!  Just change your return statement to:

```
  return sorted[sorted.length / 2];
```

You were returning an int[] (the sorted array) instead of the median value of the sorted array.

I tested with an even number of elements and it returns the first of the two middle values fyi.  You can verify the combined length is odd at the start of your method if you'd like.  Odd works as expected.  Don't forget to accept please!

Comment: Code won't even compile because of incompatible return type.

Comment: You're probably using the version where you modified the method signature.

Comment: Here's the code I have compiling with expected behavior. Only made my change. https://gist.github.com/mrgoodrich/a32a6b7d2b043ba705d5fa9d4873d97b

Comment: An array with an even length does _not_ have two medians--look it up.

Comment: @ajb then they can write code to check the length.  I was simply showing where their syntax was invalid.  Verifying the length is odd is a whole separate issue.  I did say the "first of two medians" initially though.  Thank you.

Comment: Hey thanks! I was actually just looking to merge the two sorted arrays. I wasn't looking for the median but thanks for your answer!

Comment: Dang alright, sorry I misunderstood your question. No problem!

Answer (score 0):

You are returning array and your method says int due to which code won't even compile. Use

```
public static int[] findMedianSortedArrays(int[] nums1, int[] nums2)
```

instead of

```
public static int findMedianSortedArrays(int[] nums1, int[] nums2)
```

You have to also iterate over resultant array in main method to print values.

Comment: Returning int[] violates the expected method behavior.  They're trying to get a single median value, not the sorted array.